# Set the x coord and y coord of the cards

Tags: python, pygame, coordinates, blackjack

I am trying to use pygame to make a blackjack game with card images, but it would only display 1 image. Is there any way that I could display all of them? I have tried different methods, but to no avail. Am I missing a script or line, or is there anything else that I need to do?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

 screen_width = 900
 screen_height = 600
 screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
 font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
 text_screen_title = font.render("Version 6 of BlackJack",1,(0,0,0))

 class CardRecord():
  x_coord = 0
  y_coord = 0
  image_number = 0
  face_up = False
  card_image = []
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/clubace.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/club2.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/club3.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/club4.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/club5.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/club6.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/club7.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/club8.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/club8.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/club9.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/club10.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/clubjack.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/clubking.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/clubqueen.gif'))

  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spadeace.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spade2.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spade3.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spade4.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spade5.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spade6.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spade7.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spade8.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spade9.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spade10.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spadejack.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spadeking.gif'))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load('cards/spadequeen.gif'))

  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\heartace.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\heart3.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\heart4.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\heart5.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\heart6.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\heart7.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\heart8.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\heart9.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\heart10.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\heartjack.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\heartqueen.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\heartking.gif"))

  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamondace.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamond2.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamond3.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamond4.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamond5.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamond6.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamond7.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamond8.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamond9.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamond10.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamondjack.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamondqueen.gif"))
  card_image.append(pygame.image.load("cards\diamondking.gif"))



  #Append: add an object to the list

  clock = pygame.time.Clock()



 #Initialise the array of records
  card_list = []
      #Append: add an object to the list

 clock = pygame.time.Clock()



 #Initialise the array of records
 card_list = []
 temp_X = 50
 temp_Y = 50
 i = 0
while i < 52:
  temp_card = CardRecord()
  temp_card.image_number = i
  card_list.append(temp_card)
  i = i + 1

player = []
dealer= []

i = 0
while i < 10:
   player.append(card_list[i])
   i = i + 1
   dealer.append(card_list[i])
   i = i + 1



running = True
while running == True:
  clock.tick(30)
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.ESCAPE:
        running = False


screen.fill((30,200,50))

screen.blit(text_screen_title, (100,10))
screen.blit(dealer[0].card_image[dealer[0].image_number],(dealer[0].x_coord, dealer[0].y_coord))



pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.quit()
```

I also need to find out how to set the x and y coordinates for each card. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm pretty sure the reason it only draws one card is because you told the program to only draw one card, as shown below.

```
screen.blit(dealer[0].card_image[dealer[0].image_number].image_number, (dealer[0].x_coords, dealer[0].y_coords)
```

This only draws the first index of the dealer list.

In order to draw all of the cards in the `dealer` list, we could use a `for` loop.

```
for dealercards in range(len(dealer)):
    screen.blit(dealer[dealercards].card_image[dealer[dealercards].image_number, (dealer[dealercards].x_coords, dealer[dealercards].y_coords))
```

I have to use a modified for loop because of the image_number

Also, your code is very strange. You use while loops instrad of for, ineffectively use a class, and you have a few mistakes If you fix your card class, doing there x and y positions will be easier.